# Wicked_PDF kills the server memory when too many images in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-pdf

I am using wicked_pdf to generate a pdf report in a rails 5 project. But the server gets down when there are too many images on the report. All the images are saved in the same server. And I use external css files which are located in the same directory. Image sizes are also small. Please see the code below.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :inspection_report, layout: "reports_layout" }
  format.pdf do 
    render  pdf: "inspection_report",  
            template: "pdf/inspection_report.html.erb", 
            layout: "pdf",
            margin:  {  top:    0,
                        bottom: 0,
                        left:   0,
                        right:  0 },
            viewport_size: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
  end
```

Are there any other ways to optimize this process?

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but do you use `wkhtmltopdf-binary`? Do you by any chance deploy on Heroku?

Comment: I have been using `wkhtmltopdf-binary`. As it is [deprecated](https://github.com/pallymore/wkhtmltopdf-binary#deprecated-wkhtmltopdf-binary), I tried `wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge` as well. Thanks @jvillian

Comment: This is just a problem with `wkhtmltopdf` and PDF generation in general. How much memory does your server have?

Comment: @tadman  Server memory is 1GB (DigitalOcean). Most of the time it has more than 600MB free memory. But it goes to 60MB (Free Memory) when generating a pdf with images. Any recommendations for least memory?

Comment: That's really tight for `wkhtmltopdf` since that uses the WebKit rendering engine. You'll want >4GB around for this sort of thing, ideally 8GB.